# Change data periodicity in Highcharts time series?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using the wonderful [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/), and I was wondering if there was a config option to change the data periodicity of a time series.

Like the [chart on this page](http://alpha.ons.gov.uk/#!/economy/inflationandpriceindices/timeseries/d7g7) - letting you switch from monthly to quarterly to yearly intervals.

[image]

I can add client-side code to do it if not, but since Highcharts is so powerful, I just wondered if it was a built-in option.

I can't see anything in the docs, but I'm not sure if "periodicity" is the right word for what I need!

Comment: So you want to choose different levels of "grouping" points? Are these separate datasets, or is "quarter" just an average (or similar) of the complete dataset?

Comment: @Ondkloss yes exactly. They are all the same dataset, so "quarter" will be the sum of the monthly points, ditto for "year".

Comment: Unfortunately this functionality is applied only in highstock. But you can use your own solution which will calculate new grouped points and call [setData](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.setData) to update series points.

Comment: @SebastianBochan Ah great, I have the option to use Highstock. Do you happen to know what the option is called in Highstock? I'm looking in the config options but am not sure what to search for! http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#series

Comment: GOT IT! Data grouping: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/data-grouping

Comment: And the link to the API is broken on that page, here's the actual link: http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.dataGrouping

Answer (score 1):

Here's the answer (found via @SebastianBochan).

You have to use Highstock for an inbuilt option. [Highstock documentation here](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.dataGrouping).

Otherwise you can roll your own interactions to calculate new data groupings and then call [setData](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.setData) to set the new data.